# UIStackView doesn't space equally

Tags: swift

I am applying `autolayout` and stack view with pure code.

[outcome in the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylxmH.png)

Red squares are stack views which are nested inside the black square(also a stack view).

All the arranged views inside the black `UIStackView` have height constraint. I also gave the black `UIStackView` a fixed height, a fixed width and centered it in the x and y axis.

I set the distribution of black `UIStackVIew` to equalSpacing, the spacing to 0.0, the alignment to center and the axis to vertical.

I am expecting the black `UIStackView` to automatically gives me equal spacing between the arranged views, but somehow there is a huge space between Gmail button and Facebook button.

I would like to know what I implemented in the wrong way, thanks.

Comment: You probably wanted to show a picture...

Comment: Sorry, but I can't show picture until I reach 10 reputation. I did make the link though.

Comment: may be you set height of your upper view or some view tell me if I'm wrong

Comment: What do you mean by upper view? I did explicitly set the height of the arranged views inside the black stack view. I also give the black stack view a fixed height.